# How to get the id of newly inserted data in a pivot?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this code:

```
$candidate = Applicant::find($request->candidate_id);
$candidate->jobOrders()->syncWithoutDetaching($job_id);
```

I want to return the `id` of the inserted data. So far the solution I saw was querying the last inserted data in the pivot table.

Is there other easier or more efficient way to retrieve the `id`?

Comment: Looking at the api, [syncWithoutDetaching](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.html#method_syncWithoutDetaching) returns array. What are the values in array? (Can't test right now)

Comment: A pivot table typically does not have an `id` column. The primary key is a combination of the 2 (or more) foreign keys being joined together. In your example, that would be `applicant_id` and `job_id`. If you **need** an individual ID, you likely should have a first-class table and not a pivot.

Comment: @ljubadr {attached: [11], detached: [], updated: []} --the number `11` is the value of `$job_id`

Comment: If you run `$candidate->jobOrders()->where('job_id', '=', $job_id)->get()`, you should get pivot data as well

Comment: I am using a many-to-many relationship. this will get all the rows with the same `job_id`.